# What is Ice Cream Sandwich's default design for expandable panels/ "pull down" handle?

Tags: android, design

I have to design an expandable panel for ICS with a "Pull Down" handle like this one. 
Do you know if this design is the default one for expandable panels on ICS? Or is it specific to the notification panel?

[image: ICS's notification screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circular 'pull-back-up' affordance is specific to the notification shade; I wouldn't necessarily use that elsewhere.

But wait! We generally discourage docked/expanding panels (the `SlidingDrawer` widget for developers reading this) as they can be clunky to work with on smaller screens—they tend to overly complicate the interaction surface.

Consider instead showing the expanded content in a separate screen (and don't forget to use the [Up](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) button). If you'd *really* like to maintain as much visual context as possible by not covering the full screen with expanded content, consider using a [dialog](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/dialogs.html) or [swipe views](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html).

Having said all that, if you absolutely must show an expando panel, it's fine to use mostly-universally-understood iconography that affords draggability ([example here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20928/ics-style-guide-is-there-a-standard-icon-to-indicate-drag-and-drop-in-a-list-v)).

Comment: I find that SlidingDrawer can be a fun component to use. In the app I'm currently building I use SlidingDrawer in the phone/portrait layouts to display a Fragment that in landscape would appear next to another layout. Works nicely.